# esp8266 code not working anymore

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

hi i have developed year age an Adruino application that allows me send and receive data from a mobile application using `esp8266` `esp01` back then it worked really well but now i tried to rerun the same code using a different `esp8266 esp01` the app won't work so i was wondering if the firmware flash has to do something with it because flashed the first esp firmware and the second is not but a friend of mine worked with the second one fine so here is my code

```
float Temperatur;
  String Temperatur1;
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define DEBUG true

       SoftwareSerial esp8266(8,9);
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
        esp8266.begin(9600); // your esp's baud rate might be different

  pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(11,LOW);

  pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(12,LOW);


Serial.println("Server START");
  sendCommand("AT+RST\r\n",2000,DEBUG); // reset module
  sendCommand("AT+CWMODE=2\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // configure as access point
 //sendCommand("AT+CWJAP=\"AF23_WI-FI_476C\",\"A776RAEQ\"\r\n",3000,DEBUG);
  delay(10000);
  sendCommand("AT+CIFSR\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // get ip address
  sendCommand("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // configure for multiple connections
  sendCommand("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // turn on server on port 80

  Serial.println("Server Ready");
}

void loop()
{
  /*
  Temperatur=(5.0*analogRead(A0)*100.0)/1024;
   Serial.println(Temperatur);
  Temperatur1=(5.0*analogRead(A0)*100.0)/1024.0;
   Serial.println(Temperatur1);


  if(Temperatur > 50)

   {digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(12,LOW);}
    */
  if(esp8266.available()) // check if the esp is sending a message 
  { 

     Serial.println("esp avai");
    if(esp8266.find((char*)"+IPD,"))
    {Serial.println("found ipd");
     delay(1000); // wait for the serial buffer to fill up (read all the serial data)
     // get the connection id so that we can then disconnect
     int connectionId = esp8266.read()-48; // subtract 48 because the read() function returns 
                                           // the ASCII decimal value and 0 (the first decimal number) starts at 48
//      sendHTTPResponse(connectionId,Temperatur);
     esp8266.find((char*)"pin="); // advance cursor to "pin="

     int pinNumber = (esp8266.read()-48); // get first number i.e. if the pin 13 then the 1st number is 1
     int secondNumber = (esp8266.read()-48);
     if(secondNumber>=0 && secondNumber<=9)
     {
      pinNumber*=10;
      pinNumber +=secondNumber; // get second number, i.e. if the pin number is 13 then the 2nd number is 3, then add to the first number
     }

  if((pinNumber==12)&&(pinNumber!=11))
     {digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
     digitalWrite(11,LOW);}
    if((pinNumber==11)&&(pinNumber!=12))
     {digitalWrite(12, LOW);
     digitalWrite(11,HIGH);}   
    if((pinNumber==13)&&(pinNumber!=12)&&(pinNumber!=11))
     {digitalWrite(12, LOW);
     digitalWrite(11,LOW);}   

     // build string that is send back to device that is requesting pin toggle
     String content;



     if(pinNumber==11)
     {
       content = "L'exutoire est en cours d'ouverture";
     }
     else if(pinNumber==12)
     {
       content = "L'exutoire est en cours de fermeture";
     }
     else if (pinNumber==13)
   {  content = " Il est arrêter ";}

       else if (pinNumber==10)
   {  content =  Temperatur1 ;}
     sendHTTPResponse(connectionId,content);
    }
  }else {
    Serial.println("not available");
  }
}

/*
* Name: sendData
* Description: Function used to send data to ESP8266.
* Params: command - the data/command to send; timeout - the time to wait for a response; debug - print to Serial window?(true = yes, false = no)
* Returns: The response from the esp8266 (if there is a reponse)
*/
String sendData(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
{
    String response = "";

    int dataSize = command.length();
    char data[dataSize];
    command.toCharArray(data,dataSize);

    esp8266.write(data,dataSize); // send the read character to the esp8266
    if(debug)
    {
      Serial.println("\r\n====== HTTP Response From Arduino ======");
      Serial.write(data,dataSize);
      Serial.println("\r\n========================================");
    }

    long int time = millis();

    while( (time+timeout) > millis())
    {
      while(esp8266.available())
      {

        // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window 
        char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
        response+=c;
      }  
    }

    if(debug)
    {
      Serial.print(response);
    }

    return response;
}

/*
* Name: sendHTTPResponse
* Description: Function that sends HTTP 200, HTML UTF-8 response
*/
void sendHTTPResponse(int connectionId, String content)
{

     // build HTTP response
     String httpResponse;
     String httpHeader;
     // HTTP Header
     httpHeader = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"; 
     httpHeader += "Content-Length: ";
     httpHeader += content.length();
     httpHeader += "\r\n";
     httpHeader +="Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
     httpResponse = httpHeader + content + " "; // There is a bug in this code: the last character of "content" is not sent, I cheated by adding this extra space
     sendCIPData(connectionId,httpResponse);
}

/*
* Name: sendCIPDATA
* Description: sends a CIPSEND=<connectionId>,<data> command
*
*/
void sendCIPData(int connectionId, String data)
{
   String cipSend = "AT+CIPSEND=";
   cipSend += connectionId;
   cipSend += ",";
   cipSend +=data.length();
   cipSend +="\r\n";
   sendCommand(cipSend,1000,DEBUG);
   sendData(data,1000,DEBUG);
}

/*
* Name: sendCommand
* Description: Function used to send data to ESP8266.
* Params: command - the data/command to send; timeout - the time to wait for a response; debug - print to Serial window?(true = yes, false = no)
* Returns: The response from the esp8266 (if there is a reponse)
*/
String sendCommand(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
{
    String response = "";

    esp8266.print(command); // send the read character to the esp8266

    long int time = millis();

    while( (time+timeout) > millis())
    {
      while(esp8266.available())
      {

        // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window 
        char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
        response+=c;
      }  
    }

    if(debug)
    {
      Serial.print(response);
    }

    return response;
}
```

at first i got no response from the esp  then i tried to change `esp8266.begin(9600);` to 115200  i got this

```
    Server START
    AZ+RST


    OK‡

     ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause;2, boot modd:(3,7)

    loaf 0x40100000, len 2408, soom 16 
    tail 8
    chksum 0xe5
    load 0x3ffe8000, len 776, room 0 
    tail 8
    chksum 0a tail 8m8r   S5o
Œãœ
AT+CWMODQO¦CC¡C¡jªHüAT+CIFSR
+CHFSR:APIP,"182.168.4.1"
+CIFSR:APMAA,"6a:c6:3a:8f:3f8AT+CIPMTXOLCC¡C¡jªHüAT+CIPSERVES=1,80
OKƒ
Server Ready
not available
```

Answer (score 2):

Newer ESP8266 boards have a newer version of the AT firmware on them by default. This runs at 115200 baud compared to the 9600 baud of the old ones.

However, you cannot run SoftwareSerial reliably at 115200 baud.

You need to reconfigure the ESP-01 to run at 9600 baud using the AT commands.

There are a number of different commands depending on the firmware version. One of these may work:

```
AT+IPR=9600
AT+UART_DEF=9600,8,1,0,0
AT+CIOBAUD=9600
```

Comment: thank you very much i tried to add one of them but nothing changes in fact i no longer get responses neither at 115200 baud.nor at 9600 baud and the blue led of the esp-01 is lightning

Comment: That is a common complaint. You may want to re-flash the firmware on there. There's plenty of tutorials around for how to do that.